# What is the linear analog of cusp? And difference between cusp and pole?

Tags: functions

say some function has a singular line. Is that pole? If yes then what is the difference but cusp and pole besides the former is a point and the later is line?

Comment: A singular line could be made up of cusps, poles, or both.

Answer (score 1):

A function is undefined at a pole and has values going to + or - infinity around it.

A cusp can be continuous but the slope from either side is going to + or - infinity.  The derivative of a cusp gives you a pole.

Comment: i acknowledged.